# Retrieving last 100 rows from a mysql database

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table created with an auto-increment id as a column which is also the primary key. I want to know the most efficient way to retrieve the last 100 tuples from the table (preferably O(1) time as my table is going to be huge).

Also, since id is my primary key here, will it automatically indexed? And does id being indexed result in any performance gain in retrieving the last 100 tuples?

Comment: MySQL table have any Id columns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT ... FROM t ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100;
```

**UPDATE**

Yes, your primary key will be indexed which speeds up queries using it.

Comment: so for this particular query what will be the time complexity of retrieving the last 100 rows given that my primary key is id? Thanks!

Comment: You might not wanna use `ORDER BY`, it should already be sorted by primary id.

Comment: But the result will be sorted ascending. So if you want the *last* 100 entries, you must add the `DESC` ordering.